# How to I scale a list up in size?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```py
[
  [(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)],
  [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)],
  [(2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
]
```

I want to scale it up by 3, so it looks like this:

```py
[
  [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)],
  [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)],
  [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
  [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)],
  [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)],
  [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
  [(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4)],
  [(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4)],
  [(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 4)]
]
```

Is there any way to do this that will also work for scale factors other than 3?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [example]. Questions must show a research effort.

Comment: `[[c for c in r for _ in range(3)] for r in lst for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 0):

numpy has a function to repeat elements in a given axis:

```
import numpy as np 

x = [
  [(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)],
  [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)],
  [(2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
]

x = np.repeat(x, 3, axis=0)
x = np.repeat(x, 3, axis=1)
```